# My non living appearance can't deceive

Tags: riddle, word

> Can be square, rectangle or circle
>
> And in my head, antennas can live,
>
> Nowadays, people can't live without me
>
> Although, knowing my non living appearance  can't deceive.

**Who am I?**

**HINT 1**

> Internet

Comment: We're not expected to know the specific workings of any particular internet service such as Facebook or Twitter are we?  I note that there's no knowledge tag. And what happened to the rhyme tag? Was that a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a...

> router

Can be square, rectangle or circle

> routers have these shapes

And in my head, antennas can live,

> Some routers have antennae while others are contained within the housing of the router

Nowadays, people can't live without me

> Tis true, wired or wireless, and it can be your home router or a public wireless router. Router usage on smartphones helps save those precious cellular data caps.

Although, knowing my non living appearance can't deceive.

> If it's working or not, you'll know, be it not having power or showing packet collisions, or your device showing no connectivity to the router you cannot touch or alter (public).

Comment: Correct, congratulations!

Comment: Well, I thought of that but rejected it as it doesn't seem to fit the last clue, nor the apparently incorrect Rhyme tag which has just been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a

> smartphone?

Can be square, rectangle or circle

> Smartphones can even be folded now

And in my head, antennas can live,

> There is an antenna in every smartphone

Nowadays, people can't live without me

> Well, can't deny this one

Although, knowing my non living appearance can't deceive.

> I can't see how it relates to smartphones...

Comment: You're close, think a little deeper!

Comment: Just posted a hint if you want to try again :)

Answer (score 1):

This one has been driving me nuts. Still not sure about that last line but have a guess.

Is it

> Smart speaker devices like Alexa, Echo, and Google Assistant?

It's a long shot but non living made me think of

> AI

And deceive

> rhymes with lie. "AI can't lie"

I'm very curious what the answer is, though. If I'm wrong, can you give us a hint?

Comment: Just posted a hint if you want to try again :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of

> Glasses?

Can be square, rectangle or circle

> Square, rectangle, and circle are the three of the most common lens shapes for glasses.

And in my head, antennas can live,

> Might be a reference to Google Glass, which used antennas to communicate, and was made to fit in the space of the glass frames.

Nowadays, people can't live without me

> Thanks to advances in technology, people who need glasses can get them relatively easily, whereas in the past only the rich could afford them.

Although, knowing my non living appearance can't deceive.

> May be a reference to a quote about sand that I can't think of at this time :/

Comment: Just posted a hint if you want to try again :)

Answer (score 1):

> Robots

Justification:

> They come in a variety of shapes, many of them are controlled by radio or other antenna-driven control forms, they've become increasingly critical to certain sectors of our economy, but we still don't have any way to make one that actually looks like a human.

Comment: Just posted a hint if you want to try again :)

Answer (score 1):

You’re an:

> Online avatar

Can be square, rectangle or circle

> Many sites allow you to choose avatar image shape

And in my head, antennas can live

> Several use default images of a head with an antenna, eg the Mozilla Common Voice project

Nowadays, people can't live without me

> It seems a lot of people can’t, anyway

My non living appearance can't deceive

> It’s obvious that I don’t really look like that.

Comment: Don’t know where the rhyme tag comes in, though.

Comment: Just posted a hint if you want to try again :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's

> Operating System?

Can be square, rectangle or circle

> Different shapes of logos, eg. rectangle - Windows, MacOS, circle - Ubuntu etc.
>  Or different shape of monitors, regular square/rectangular ones, circular as in smartwatches etc.

And in my head, antennas can live,

> Android OS' logo has antennas in it's head

Nowadays, people can't live without me

> Well, can't deny it. Almost everything now works on some kind of operating system. Computers, phones, cars, even medical equipment

Although, knowing my non living appearance can't deceive.

> Not sure about this one, maybe since user can control the OS, he always knows what's going on inside? And since it's computer "program", it does not have capabilities of lying? Farfetched, but it's my only idea right now :)

Comment: Just posted a hint if you want to try again :)

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

> **television**

### Reasoning

#### Can be square, rectangle or circle

> TV’s can be square or circular (older ones) or can be rectangular (modern TV’s).

#### And in my head, antennas can live,

> Modern television don’t have visible antennae, but older ones have ones that stick out of the top (head).

#### Nowadays, people can't live without me

> This is pretty obvious. Many people “live” on their televisions.

#### Although, knowing my non living appearance can't deceive.

> The TV screen shows many different images besides what it really is.

### Alternative Answer

> Phones for all of the same reasons :)